# Scale Image to Full Width and Zoom

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I have an image that I am using to fill the full width of the browser, but restrained to a certain height. It's working BUT if the user makes their browser window bigger than a certain point it gives white space on the side. How do I tell it to then zoom the image effectively to still take up the full width when scaled?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="category-image">
  <img src="http://www.sfsuicide.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/flower-banner.jpg"></img>
</div>

.category-image img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

p.category-image, .category-description {
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    position: relative;
    height: 450px;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grRGBe

I tried adding in: min-width: 200%; but it just stretches the image (not zooms).

Answer (score 2):

Try adding width via viewport size (set to be 100% the width of the browser size).

`.category-image img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height: auto;
    width: 100vw;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}`

Alternatively, it may be beneficial to make it a background image instead, depending on use/context.

Comment: Thanks, that just distorts the image though and the height has to be fixed (not auto). Unfortunately it can't be a background image based on how it is setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {

    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background: url(http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af2/pipewun/Awwshop/DSCF0951.jpg) center fixed no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the image can't be a background though based on how it is setup.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in your CodePen.

```
body {
  background: url('http://www.sfsuicide.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/flower-banner.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

What this is doing:

1. Grabbing the body tag itself with "body {"
2. setting the background of the body tag to an image with "background: url(..."
3. Setting the background to not repeat, becuase it likes to repeat by default.
4. Centering the background, if you want it aligned to the top of the page then this needs to be changed to "center top"
5. This one is the magical element that makes it do what you want... Setting the size to cover makes the background enlarge to fill the entire space, even if the image is not that big.  Cover is what I used, see this W3Schools page to see what your options are and what exactly you want your background to do.
   http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the image can't be a background though based on  how it is setup.

Comment: IVCatalina, check out my other answer on this thread, accomplishes the same task with using an image instead of setting the image as a background in css. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative answer to my above answer... simpler, I have not extensively tested it but it appears to work as expected when I stretch the window across my 3 monitors.

apply this to your CSS your code pen... :)

```
.category-image img {
        min-width:100%;
    }

    p.category-image, .category-description {
        margin-bottom: 35px;
        position: relative;
        height: 450px;
    }
```